# How to do a bulkload to Hbase from CSV from command line

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to do a bulkload which is a csv file using command line.

This is what I am trying

```
bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles hdfs://localhost:9000/transactionsFile.csv bulkLoadtable
```

The error I am getting is below:

```
15/09/01 13:49:44 WARN mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles: Skipping non-directory hdfs://localhost:9000/transactionsFile.csv
15/09/01 13:49:44 WARN mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles: Bulk load operation did not find any files to load in directory hdfs://localhost:9000/transactionsFile.csv.  Does it contain files in subdirectories that correspond to column family names?
```

Is it possible to do bulkload from command line without using java mapreduce.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost correct, only thing missed is that the input to the `bulkLoadtable` must be directory. I suggest to keep the csv file under a directory and pass the path upto directory name as an argument to the command. Please refer the below link.

https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/LoadIncrementalHFiles.html#doBulkLoad(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Admin,%20org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Table,%20org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RegionLocator)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Alka, were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do bulk load from command line,

There are multiple ways to do this,

1. a. Prepare your data by creating data files (StoreFiles) from a MapReduce job using HFileOutputFormat.

   b. Import the prepared data using the completebulkload tool

   eg: hadoop jar hbase-VERSION.jar completebulkload [-c /path/to/hbase/config/hbase-site.xml] /user/todd/myoutput mytable

   [more details](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/arch.bulk.load.html), 
   [hbase bulk load](http://krishnaprasadas.blogspot.in/2012/09/fastest-hbase-write-using-hbase-bulk.html)

2.
Using **importtsv** 
eg:

hbase> hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.separator=,  -Dimporttsv.columns="HBASE_ROW_KEY,id,temp:in,temp:out,vibration,pressure:in,pressure:out" sensor hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:/tmp/hbase.csv
[more details](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/4942/import-csv-data-into-hbase-using-importtsv.html)